# Specify generic return type without relying on arguments in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

I'm working on adding python type annotations to an existing codebase. I have a function that takes in a set of database IDs, checks if the user has permissions to view the underlying models, and then returns the list of models. The existing type annotations look something like:

```py
AuthorizeableModel = TypeVar["ModelType", lower=HasAuthMixin]

def bulk_load_and_check_auth(model_ids: List[str]) -> List[AuthorizeableModel]:
    # ...
```

This isn't wrapped in a class since this can be used to bulk fetch a heterogeneous list of models. However, the `HasAuthMixin` type is pretty thin and oftentimes I need to do more complicated stuff with the return value of that function.

In typescript I could create a function signature like:

```
function bulkLoadAndCheckAuth<T extends AuthorizeableModel>(dbIds: Array<str>): List<T> {
  // logic
```

and then I could specify the expected type of the function

```
const models = bulkLoadAndCheckAuth<MyModel>(idsList);
```

Is there any way to do something similar with python types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python generic type argument can be applied only in the case of classes.

However, classes can be callable, hence there is the following *hack* to achieve what you want:

```py
AuthorizeableModel = TypeVar("AuthorizeableModel", bound=HasAuthMixin)


class _bulkLoadAndCheckAuthType:
    def __call__(self, model_ids: list[str]) -> list[HasAuthMixin]:
        ...

    def __getitem__(
        self, _: type[AuthorizeableModel]
    ) -> Callable[[list[str]], list[AuthorizeableModel]]:
        return self  # type: ignore


bulk_load_and_check_type = _bulkLoadAndCheckAuthType()

models = bulk_load_and_check_type[MyModel](["id1", "id2"])

reveal_type(models) # Revealed type is "builtins.list[MyModel]
```

Comment: Why not `Generic` here? It would be not hacky (one of standard patterns), does not interfere with runtime (`__class_getitem__` usage for other purposes is discouraged) + is understandable for others.